# "bad ptr" with static buffers on some PCs

Tags: visual-c++, pointers, static, buffer

I have a command line application that converts files to my format and a plug-in which enables another application to read my format but the plug-in has some weird problems on some PCs.

The command line application and plug-in share the same code for accessing the files and the CLI works on all tested PCs but the plug-in gives some serious problems on some PCs and always with the same operations.

I already tried debugging it but it just makes no sense, I have some static buffers which are declared "#pragma omp threadprivate" as they are used by multiple threads and some of these are "bad ptr" on two windows XP PCs but not on windows 7, how can this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is Windows XP vs Windows 7 Issue. All i can seems to be timing issue rather os causing the issue though. What kind thread synch you  are running on your application

Comment: I'm only using OpenMP to speed up buffer compression/decompression and there is no synchronization needed (at least not that I know of), every thread has its own data to process.